# Issue in Calling functions in another JS file in ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I have an asp .net MVC application. I have a view index.cshtml. I have two JS files:- Master.js and Child.js. All JS functions are defined in Master.js and those functions are used in Child.js file.

I am getting following error: Object doesn't support property or method 'method1'.

If I copy whole code of Master.js and place it above code of Child.js, then it works very fine in MVC application.

Both JS files are working fine with ASP.NET web forms application.

I tried to load master.js file in _layouts.cshtml and child.js index.cshtml. I was hoping that master.js will load before child.js.

index.cshtml:-

```
@section JavaScript    
{        
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></ script>
    <script src="../Scripts/child.js" type="text/javascript"></s cript>
}
```

layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Master.js")
    @RenderSection("javascript", false)
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()      
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Additional Information:

In Master.js: I am extending the method as follows:

```
$.fn.method1 = function()
{
   //My Code
};
```

I child.js : I am using the method as follows:

```
$('#MyDiv').method1();
```

I came across following link:

[Problems with Jquery function extend in MVC4](http://forums.asp.net/t/1886906.aspx?MVC4%20appears%20not%20to%20like%20the%20JQuery%20fn%20extend%20syntax%20)

Comment: have you checked the name is matching and remember those should be case sensitive match?

Comment: try to right those method directly into pages and see if it works

Comment: if above things you have already tried or didnt work then copy your method and show us how you are calling it

Comment: Yes I have referred the JS files with accurate names.

Comment: @AkshayP In the browser (html code) which javascript reference appears first Master.js or child.js? And look whether they are loaded properly or not.

Comment: I think it is problem due to extending the function using JQuery - I will edit my question with additional information.

Comment: If your `"~/Master.js"` bundle has the extension method, this will not work, since your jQuery reference is added later.

Answer (score 0):

I normally wrap extension functions like so:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.method1 = function() {
       //My Code
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This seems to be the recommended way to go, according to the [documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/); it helps avoid conflicts on the `$` object.

> [...] To work well with other plugins, and still use
>   the jQuery $ alias, we need to put all of our code inside of an
>   Immediately Invoked Function Expression, and then pass the function
>   jQuery, and name the parameter $

If you're trying to load these scripts via the bundler, you need something like:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerywithcustomscripts").Include(
                    "~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/scripts/master.js",
                    "~/scripts/child.js"));
    }
}
```

with this in your _Layout.cshtml:

```
Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerywithcustomscripts")
```

Comment: I will try it now and let you know

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working for me. It is giving me same error. Is it some kind of limitation of JQuery to implement function extend in MVC application..?

Comment: No, I primarily work with ASP.NET MVC, and I've written and used a handful of extension functions.

Comment: Clean up your question to only include what you're using now, and add the relevant bits of your BundleConfig.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are including your Master.js function before you include jQuery. When rendered, your header section would look like this when sent to the browser:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/modernizr"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/master.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"> </script>
    <script src="../Scripts/child.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
</head>
```

If you're extending jQuery in master.js, you need to include jQuery before the master.js reference.  The reason why it probably works when you copy all of the code from master.js to child.js is because by that point jQuery has been defined.